# How are non-roman Unicode characters encoded in a domain name?

Tags: iphone, url, dns, resolution

Say I have a URL such as:

```
http://ほっけがおいしい.com
```

If I put this in any browser, I insto-magically get:

```
http://xn--n8jaqhy3b1euj.com/
```

What is the algorithm to transcode the Unicode characters into mere latin ones?  This seems like it should be easily Google-able but I really can't seem to find anything.

I want to reverse it -- given the latter, I want to get the former.

The use case is that I want to pass some information on the iPhone between apps using URL handlers, but I can't guarantee that the content will be Latin characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this covers it all, I've not read through all the RFCs but it might be a good place to start: [RFCs Related to IDN](http://www.icann.org/en/topics/idn/rfcs.htm)